# discord.ext problems with sending in right channel and setting status

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm using discord.py, and from there the discord.ext module. I have a quite long selenium code running in a `while True` loop. Here's part of it:

```
@bot.command()
    async def start(ctx):
        driver.install_addon(r'some_extension.xpi')
        channel = bot.get_channel(791352165393498203)
        user = bot.get_user(257428782233812993)
        while True:
            await bot.change_presence(status=Status.online)
            driver.get('some_link')
            driver.maximize_window()
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pageSize"]').click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                await ctx.channel.send(f" We had an Exception, please go check")
                time.sleep(60)
                driver.refresh()
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pageSize"]').click()
                time.sleep(1)
                await ctx.channel.send(f"Problem solved")
```

Most of this code works fine, but there are two main problems, and I don't get an exception.

- Firstly, the `await ctx.channel.send(f"We had an Exception, please go check")` should be sent in the channel I stated above, but it
  doesn't. `pycharm` says that the channel variable is never used,
  which shouldn't be the case.
- Secondly, the `await bot.change_presence(status=Status.online)` doesn't keep the bot
  permanently displayed as online.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Just use `channel.send()` without `ctx`, `ctx` is a bunch of info about used command (author, channel, etc.).
2. You don't need to change status to online, it's automatically setting when you launch the bot.

Oh, and i recommend to use `asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()` because, when u use `time.sleep()` the bot will stop working in this time, and will not responding to any command/event.

Comment: I read about the ansyncio as well, if you say it would then respond to other commands ima try that. I actually need to change my status tho because the bot is running like 24/7 with only a start command, and after a few minutes it goes offline. I will try the channel.send(), but it doesnt really seem to make sense to me

Comment: Alright after changeing the time.sleep by asyncio.sleep the online status worked, and channel.send instead of ctx.channel.send worked as well. Thanks!